# Definitions of a geometric algebra/exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometric-algebras

I'm interested in exterior algebra and similar topics and I'm reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Definition_and_notation
I've got two questions:

1. Do you assess this definition is formally correct? In my opinion: it's not. In particular $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ in $A, B, C\in \mathcal{G}(p,q)$ is another $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ than $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ in $AB \in \mathcal{G}(p,q)$ isn't it? But the "definition" doesn't explain what set $AB$ belongs to and hence it loops. The definition also doesn't say what the codomain of $g$.
2. Where the second equation in $$\frac{1}{2}(ab + ba) = \frac{1}{2}\left((a + b)^2 - a^2 - b^2\right) = a \cdot b$$ comes from?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. a) Do you assess the definition is formally correct?

Yes, it's fine.  It just says "the exterior algebra is the Clifford algebra with the zero bilinear form."

> 1. b) In particular $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ in $A, B, C\in \mathcal{G}(p,q)$ is another $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ than $\mathcal{G}(p,q)$ in $AB \in \mathcal{G}(p,q)$ isn't it? But the "definition" doesn't explain what set $$ belongs to and hence it loops.

I have no idea what that means.  The only place I see $AB$ is in the list of properties (I hope you didn't take that to be a definition. It seems you may have.) And that one place seems to say *exactly* what set $AB$ belongs to, and you seem to have typed it no less than 5 times above... I don't think any looping is involved because there isn't really any defining going on at that point.

> 1. c) The definition also doesn't say what the codomain of $$.

It's true it doesn't explicitly say it here, but a "bilinear form $g$ on $F$ vector space $V$" means a function $g:V\times V\to F$ with special properties.

> 2. Where the second equation in [...] comes from? [sic]

For vectors $a,b$ and a bilinear form $B$ for a field that's not characteristic $2$, there is always a way to separate $B$ into symmetric and antisymmetric pieces. That's what that equation is doing. Actually, this is something that is done more generally [for tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor#Antisymmetric_and_symmetric_tensors), and a bilinear form is just an example of a $2$ tensor.

In this particular case you can just verify it using basic algebra. There is not much to say about the equation.

Comment: I've got a limit of characters so I'll write only that I've figured out where the equation $$\frac{1}{2}((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2)=a \cdot b$$ comes from. From the last property $$ (a+b)^2=g(a+b, a+b) \mathbb 1 $$ and similarly for $a^2$ and $b^2$ so it follows that $$(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2=2g(a,b)\mathbb 1.$$ But it also follows that the definition $$a \cdot b:=g(a,b)$$ is wrong and it should be $$a \cdot b :=g(a,b) \mathbb 1$$ instead. Am I right? 
One more question. What is the relation between $V$ and $\mathcal G(p,q)$? Is this the same set?

Comment: @PLrc $V$ is embedded as a subspace in $G(p,q)$, and if you take its elements and form linear combinations of products of its elements (with the geometric product), you generate all of $G(p,q)$. I’ll address the earlier part later.

Comment: will you adress the first question? :P The unit vector seems to be missing in many places at Wikipedia, for instance here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Clifford_algebras in the equation $$xy+yx=2g(x,y).$$ As a matter of fact: how is defined vector multiplication in the algebra (over a field) when $V=\mathbb C^n$?

Comment: @PLrc The question from he comment? Thanks for the reminder.  I’m still on my phone, so later. Strictly speaking the quaternions doesn’t have to be norm $1$, but that makes it more standard form.

Comment: @PLrc If you think it’s “wrong” then I guess you don’t know about the standard convention that the scalars are identified with the $0$ grade elements.  It is reasonably written.

Comment: But $xy+yx$ is a vector, whereas $2g(x,y)$ is not. Am I right?

Comment: @PLrc $xy+yz$ is always a grade $0$ element.  The vectors are grade 1

Comment: I thought notation $xy$ means vector multiplication in algebra which result is also a vector. It seems it folows from what is said in the above mentioned article: 
"The Clifford algebra $Cℓ(V, g)$ is the algebra generated by $V$ along with the anticommutation relation $xy + yx = 2g(x, y)$. It is an abstract version of the algebra generated by the gamma or Pauli matrices."

Comment: @PLrc Well, everything in the algebra is technically a vector, it’s just not the norm to refer to them that way.  Usually you say the grade $1$ things are vectors, grade 0 things are scalars, higher grades are multivectors.  The geometric product of two grade 1 things is either grade 0, grade 2, or a sum of two things like that. It’s never grade $1$.  Clearer?

Comment: An example would be appreciated :) I thought that such geometric product can be for example matrix multiplication.

Comment: @PLrc You can represent elements of any finite dimensional algebra as matrixes and use matrix multiplication.  But that is unimportant here.  Examples? If $e_i$ are elements of an orthonormal basis for the usual real inner product, $e_1e_1=1$. Or $e_1e_2=e_1\wedge e_2$.  And $e_1(e_1+e_2)=1+e_1\wedge e_2$. Anything works...